# Zipping and Emailing the documents of document library in sharepoint 2010

Tags: email

I need the procedure to zipping all the files in the document library of sharepoint 2010 and email that zipped file using aspx and c# coding.

Can any have any idea about this concept....?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for that request would be pretty simple.

This solution will be in 3 parts :

1. Create a custom list ribbon element that will trigger the zip action
2. The triggered action (a page or server side code) would zip the content of the list.  For that, you could use the external library [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/2.).  You will produce an In-Memory stream that will be used in step 3.
3. Send an email with the built-in System.Net.Mail in the .NET framework.  The SPUtilities.SendEmail(...) can't be good, you can't send attachment from it...

There you go, that would be the easiest way of doing it!  I did it for SP2007, and it's quite simple!